# Where is the Ethics in Deep Ecology?

Tags: ethics, pragmatism, environmental-philosophy

Norwegian philosopher and activist Arne Naess (1912–2009) is credited as a pioneer of the environmental movement and the first to coin the term "deep ecology." Distinguishing between deep and shallow ecological thinking, Naess taught the importance of valuing biodiversity, including the interrelationships between human and natural existence. There is intrinsic value to the flourishing of human and nonhuman life on earth.

What is striking is how Naess addressed the debate about whether this value should be seen aesthetically or morally. Those wanting to avoid the aestheticizing of morals were worried that a clearly defined ethics for the environmentalists needed to be worked out. When asked what kind of moral or ethical movement deep ecology was, Naess responded in an off-putting manner: "I'm not much interested in ethics or morals, I'm interested in how we experience the world..." (https://philarchive.org/archive/BUTTEP).

How should we take this remark? Is it a flippant reply or a testament to Naess's endorsement of a pragmatic ethics that, being unconcerned with adopting the right theory whether it be virtue, deontology, or utilitarian, seeks to solve problems?